# Where can I find documentation for React component methods?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for an explanation of parameters for each component method such as `componentDidUpdate()`. I see the link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate but it does not provide any explanation of the parameters such as `prevProps`, `prevState`, and `snapshot`. Where can I find documentation that describes them?

Is my current understanding of the parameters correct?

`prevProps`: The props object before `render()` was called by a change in either state or props.

`prevState`: The state object before `render()` was called by a change in either state or props.

`snapshot`: ???

Comment: If `prevProps` and `prevState` are confusing then may I suggest you start from the beginning of the react docs and try to first understand what `state` and `props` are? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevState` and `prevProps` are the `state` and `props` from the previous render cycle, as opposed to `this.state` and `this.props` from the current render cycle.

The `snapshot` comes from [`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

> Any value returned by this lifecycle will be passed as a parameter to
>   `componentDidUpdate()`.

You can find the react component documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the documentation there are a few good blog posts on the web explaining the various lifecycle methods, when to use them and how they work:

https://blog.logrocket.com/the-new-react-lifecycle-methods-in-plain-approachable-language-61a2105859f3/

https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1?gi=3ac3c7c8ff34

Answer (score 1):

A far as I know there is no other, more specific documentation about lifeCycleMethods.

Parameters such as `prevProps` and `prevState` are pretty much self-explanatory. Even if someone isn't sure what they are, `console.log(prevProps, prevState)` could help. My assumption is that self-explanatory nature of these parameters is what makes them ommited from detailed explanation in docs.

On the other hand, `snapshop` which is not that much self-explanatory is explained:

> If your component implements the getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() lifecycle (which is rare), the value it returns will be passed as a third “snapshot” parameter to componentDidUpdate(). Otherwise this parameter will be undefined.